# Быстрый insert в базу данных из R

Tags: r

Знакомлюсь с R. Пока довольно непросто он дается. 
Имеется у меня data frame из примерно 240000 строк, полученный из файла. Я присваиваю нужные мне столбцы к переменным (кстати, не знаю каким образом это происходит, наверное, создается ссылка на те же области в памяти).

```
ips <- info$V1
datas <- info$V4
scenarios <- info$V6
baskets <- info$V9
```

Теперь подключаюсь к базе данных и выгружаю туда эти данные через цикл for.

```
len <- length(ips)
for (i in 1:len) {
  query <- "INSERT INTO info VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)"
  res <- dbSendQuery(con, query)
  dbBind(res, list(i, ips[i], datas[i], scenarios[i], baskets[i]))
  dbClearResult(res)
}
dbDisconnect(con)
```

Наверняка постоянное обращение по индексу и выполнение отдельного запроса для каждый строки - не самый лучший вариант. Можно ли сделать быстрее? На выполнение этого цикла уходит минуты 2-3.

Comment: О какой базе данных идёт речь? Для многих драйверов реализован метод `dbWriteTable`. Для многих БД также есть возможность загрузить CSV, чир является наиболее эффективным способ после загрузки из дампа. Или же можно сделать это с помощью `dbExecute`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в статье ["Взаимодействие R с базами данных на примере Microsoft SQL Server и других СУБД"](https://habr.com/ru/post/461063/) я очень поробно постарался описать как R взаимодействует с БД.

Описанный метод подойдёт для любой базы. В целом вам надо использовать для записи пакет `DBI` и функцию `dbWriteTable()`, цикл для записи вовсе не нужен.